# Neovim GitHub Copilot NotSignedIn, but Authenticated

Tags: authentication, neovim, github-copilot

GitHub Copilot in NeoVim was always working, up until five minutes ago.
The response from the server is "[Copilot] Not Authenticated: NotSignedIn", but when I do
:Copilot auth
It says "[Copilot] Authenticated as Github user XYZ".

I did not change anything, and it does not seem to work, even after plugin reinstallation or system restart. The plugin seems to have no "logout" option either.

I am using the "zbirenbaum/copilot.lua" plugin in AstroNvim.

Is there a way to "deauth" somehow? The only available commands to me are:
auth, attach, detach, disable, enable, panel, status, suggestion, toggle, version.

I have tried uninstalling the plugin and reinstalling it, restarting my system, doing ":Copilot detach", ":Copilot disable", ":Copilot toggle", and also ":Copilot auth" to reauth, but it uses the old session I believe.

Answer (score 1):

remove `~/.config/github-copilot/hosts.json` to delete auth information. [issue #169](https://github.com/zbirenbaum/copilot.lua/issues/169)

Comment: As I said, I had already found the problem: Auth did not work through a certain vpn.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. I read online that using a proxy would cause this issue, but I had already disconnected from my VPN.

But! Apple macOS includes an option in the WiFi settings to "Limit IP address tracking" which completely breaks Copilots network connection.